# Negative coordinates in UIView.frame

Tags: objective-c

I have an UIView with frame: CGRectMake(0,0,1024,768);

And I want to set (0,0) point of that subview to (0, 512);

I tried:

```
CGRect fr = self.frame;
fr.origin.x = self.bounds.size.width / 2;
self.frame = fr;
```

It seems ok, but negative coordinates doesn't work. I want x from -512 to 512.

What should I do make negative coords work?

Comment: What is the final frame that you want ? CGRectMake(-512,0,1024,768) ?

Comment: yep, but x=-512 should be on the screen at left side

Comment: I will try to explain what I have understood here. You want you view to stay in the same place. But you want the coordinate values to be shifted by - width/2. Is that right ?

Comment: pic: http://flockdraw.com/gallery/view/1123187

Comment: :) I updated my answer, does it work for you now?

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to achieve? Is this view drawn with `drawRect:`? A view's coordinate system is not changed by simply changing the frame...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want to transform the frame of your view to `CGRectMake(-512,0,1024,768)`

If that's the case do

```
fr.origin.x = - self.bounds.size.width / 2;
```

instead of

```
fr.origin.x = self.bounds.size.width / 2;
```

You can use the following to get the same result:

```
self.frame = CGRectInset(self.frame, -CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), 0);
```

If this is not what you are looking for, please clarify your question.

**Edit**

After the clarification, I think the only way to achieve this is to have a parent view with coordinates CGRectMake(512,0,1024,768) and with clipsToBounds = NO. Then add you view to this parent view at frame CGRectMake(-512,0,1024,768).

```
UIView *parentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(512,0,1024,768)];
parentView.clipsToBounds = NO;
[originalParentView addSubview:parentView]; // or controller.view = parentView;

[parentView addSubview:view];
view.frame = CGRectMake(-512,0,1024,768);
```

Comment: no, that's not I'm looking for - your code just moves frame, but I need frame on the same coords. Only thing I need is to change coordinate system in uiview: left-top corner should be -512,0 and right-top corner 512,0

Answer (score 0):

Try `CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1024.0f, 768.0f)` instead of what you currently use.

Then, you'll want to do the following.

```
CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
frame.origin.x = self.bounds.size.width / 2.0f;
self.view.frame = frame;
```

Try that.

Comment: It doesn't work too.

I tried your code and negative coords doesn't work again

Comment: I think what sch has posted will work for what you are trying to do. However, you may need to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to do. Nothing here should be creating a negative number.

See if these ideas help:

1. When you divide a float use 2.0f, not just 2.

   fr.origin.x = self.bounds.size.width / 2.0f;
2. Maybe it would be easier to think about where you want the center of the view.

   self.center = CGPointMake(0.0f, 512.0f);

Comment: 1. ok, thank you!
2. no, I need to set 0,0 of my view in self.frame.size.width/2.0f

Comment: You mean like self.center = CGPointMake(-512.0f, 0.0f); The coding should be easy, just not sure exactly what you mean.